# Why Giving Null?

Tags: java, output, composition

Okaii so i wrote the two classes , did the main too (Still testing, not done yet ) , after running it , it gives null in the output , which means the default value.. why ?

**Location class**  ( With setters and getters )

```
public class Location {

public String city;
public String street;

public Location() {
}

public Location(String city, String street) {
    this.city = city;
    this.street = street;
}



@Override
public String toString(){
    return "City Is : " + city + " \nStreet Is : " + street;

}
```

}

**And this is the composition in property class :** (Also with setters and getters )

```
public Location location = new Location();
    public static int counter = 0;

    public Property(int ID, Location location) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.location = new Location();
        counter++;
    }
public String toString() {
        return "\nID is : " + ID + "\nLocation is : \n" + location.toString();
    }
```

**And the output is :**

Enter Propery ID :
123
 Enter Property City and Street :
test
test1
 Do you want to Enter more Property Data ?
no
 Choose One of the Options from the following menu : 
 1- List all properties. For each property display its id and location
 2- List all properties locations. For each property display only the location
 3- List all the ids of all properties that are in a certain given city (read the city)
 4- Given a property id change its location city (read the id and the new value of city)
 5- Display the location of a property given its id if it is found in the array (read the id)
 6- Display the number of properties
 7- Exit
1

---

Property 1
ID is : 123
Location is : 
City Is : null 
Street Is : null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Property` constructor, I think you should have

```
this.location = location;
```

Comment: This worked ! i had it as a method.. now it's the variable in the constructor, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In the Property class: `this.location = new Location();` instead of using the `location` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your location's empty constructor doesn't initialize the fields `city` and `street` so when you build a Location object with that constructor you need to ensure to set those values manually. Or just delete that constructor and use only this:

```
public Location(String city, String street) {
    this.city = city;
    this.street = street;
}
```